# Laravel json response has back slashes

Tags: json, laravel

When I return just a profile like

```
return $profile->toJson();
```

The json string looks perfect but when I do

```
return Response::json(array('success' => 'true', 'profile' => $profile->toJson()));
```

The profile part of the json string as all these backslashes before the quotes.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you are converting to JSON two times. Try this:

```
return Response::json(array('success' => 'true', 'profile' => $profile));
```

Comment: I did try it return:
{"success":"true","profile":{"incrementing":true,"timestamps":true,"exists":true}}

Comment: Where the $profile->toJson() in the first example shows every attribute